# Dynamically loading table body content w/out changing table headers

Tags: javascript, html

html:

```js
     $("#submit").click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault()
         data = {
                start_date: start_date,
                end_date: end_date,
                name: name,
                code: code,
                extra_code: extra_code
            }
    
         $("tbody").load("http://127.0.0.1:5000/filter?"+ $.param(data), function(response, status, xhr ){
                $("tbody").append(response)
            })
```

```html
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover" id="table2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Heading A</th>
                    <th>Heading B</th>
                    <th>Heading C</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 {% if users %}
                        {% for user in users %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ user.date }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.event_body }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.code }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.extra_code }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

there is a filter button on my page and when I click it the entire table gets reloaded which makes it look weird

my question is how can we only manipulate the table body? so when the user clicks the submit button the `load` method will fire and only add the table rows?

Comment: What is the expected response type? is it json or xml or just a plain html? Do you make an ajax call for filtering the data?

Comment: @Bogie expected response is html and yes ajax is called with load

Comment: Do you use pagination?

Answer (score 1):

I was also in a similar situation where i needed data from a PHP server to be displayed inside a HTML table as rows / tr within the tbody only.

I was able to attain it using HTML and jQuery.

just place the table in HTML with a thead and tbody, the thead will contain the static headers and the tbody has an id to identify it in jQuery and will be filled with dynamic data.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>Status</td>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="myTbody">

</tbody>
```

Then i use jQuery to get dynamic data from PHP and display them as tr's in the tbody.

```
$("#myTbody").html(ret_ajxdata2.output);
```

The output is gotten with Ajax by getting values from a php file. The php file that give the output arranges the output in tr's for each unique record am getting. The php...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    $out = "";


    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        //RESULTS FOUND

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            // output data of each row

            $out .= '<tr class="tr-entry">';
            $out .= '<td>' . $row["id"] . '</td>';
            $out .= '<td>' . $row["description"] . '</td>';
            $out .= '<td>' . $row["no"] . '</td>';
            $out .= '<td>' . $row["status"] . '</td>';
            $out .= '</tr>';


        }

        $return["msg"] = "Products Found";
        $return["error"] = false;
        $return["output"] = $out;


    } else {
        //RESULTS NOT FOUND
        $return["msg"] = "No products found";
        $return["error"] = true;
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
```

Maybe you can arrange all tr data in the server side to make the output be simply inserted in the tbody of the client when its sent. Hope it is helpful in solving your problem.